# Installing Windows Phone SDK 7.1 in Windows 8 Developer Preview

Tags: windows-8-preview, windows-phone

Is it possible to install the Windows Phone SDK 7.1 on Windows 8 Developer Preview?

I am planning to test Windows 8 on my main machine.